# iAds not hiding

Tags: iphone, hide, iad

I have IBOutlet on bottom of the screen for ADBannerView, and I won't to hide it when it shows white screen (not able to load an Ad).

I have this code, but it is not working:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"showAd" context:nil];

    CGRect adBannerViewFrame = [bannerView frame];
    adBannerViewFrame.origin.x = 160;
    adBannerViewFrame.origin.y = 523;

    bannerView.frame = adBannerViewFrame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"hideAd" context:nil];

    CGRect adBannerViewFrame = [bannerView frame];
    adBannerViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
    adBannerViewFrame.origin.y = 0;

    bannerView.frame = adBannerViewFrame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Can you help me please, I'm struggling with it for past two hours... :/

Comment: why haven't use block-based animation? why not the centre of the `ADBannerView` has been changed?

Comment: But this approach should work too. Even if I delete [UIView beginAnimations:@"hideAd" context:nil]; and [UIView commitAnimations];, it is still not moved on screen.

Comment: check my answer, I would drop the old `-beginAnimation:context:` method as the Apple recommends in every case in iOS4+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try something like this (this is from a live project). the iAd banner is at the bottom of the screen and it goes down when it becomes invisible, and it comes up back when it must be visible.

the `_isiADBannerVisible` is just a simple `Boolean` variable.

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    if (_isiADBannerVisible == false) {
         _isiADBannerVisible = true;

         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
             [banner setFrame:CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0.f, -50.f)];
         } completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (_isiADBannerVisible == true) {
         _isiADBannerVisible = false;

         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
             [banner setFrame:CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0.f, +50.f)];
         } completion:nil];

    }
}
```